# Mono: Load an assembly from an injected dll on a process

Tags: c#, c++, .net, mono, .net-assembly

I'm trying to load an assembly from an injected dll ( c++ ) ,

First I hook :

```
pMono1 = (Mono1Fn)DetourFunction((PBYTE)GetProcAddress(addr,"mono_assembly_load_from_full"), (PBYTE)Mono1); 
pMono2 = (Mono2Fn)GetProcAddress(addr, "mono_image_open_full"); 
mono_jit_exec_ = (mono_jit_exec_t)GetProcAddress(addr,"mono_jit_exec");
pMonoDomainGet = (mono_domain_get_t)GetProcAddress(addr,"mono_domain_get");
```

(I've checked that addr is correct )

Then what I do is

```
MonoAssembly* __cdecl Mono1(MonoImage *image, const char*fname, MonoImageOpenStatus *status, gboolean refonly) 
{
   if(!Loaded)
  {
    Loaded = true;
    OpenAssembly();


  }

return pMono1(image,fname,status,refonly); 
}
```

So, what I'm trying to do is:

When the target process opens an assembly, I open mine and the original assembly to load

But the problem is : the opened assembly doesnt run.

Here is the method OpenAssembly():

```
void OpenAssembly()
{
    MonoImageOpenStatus status = MONO_IMAGE_ERROR_ERRNO;
    MonoImage *Image = (MonoImage*)pMono2("B:\\AsmTest.dll",&status,FALSE);
    MonoAssembly *Assm =  (MonoAssembly*)Mono1(Image,"B:\\AsmTest.dll",&status,FALSE);
    char* in[] = {"B:\\AsmTest.dll" };
    cout << "In[0] : " << in[0] << endl;
    mono_jit_exec_((MonoDomain*)pMonoDomainGet(),Assm,0,in);

}
```

In the embedding mono tutorial they say that `mono_jit_exec` calls the Main method,

but it doesnt,( which leads me to think that the error is in my assembly ),

Here the code of the simple Assembly :

```
 public class AssemblyTest 
{

    static void Main()
    {


        MessageBox.Show("I do WORK :d");




    }
}
```

So like I said before , my problem is that the `Main()` method never gets called in the process.(Because the MessageBox doesnt show up)

For your information : I've put the assembly in B disk.

I think my problem is so simple, but I cant find why.

Thanks in advance, I hope you understand what I mean :)